# pygtk - spinbutton: output-signal

Tags: callback, pygtk, text-formatting

I use a spinbutton in my application to let the user choose a number between -1 and 100. In my application -1 means Infinity. So I want to show the text "Infinity", if the user selects the value -1. This is my code:

```
def spin_output(spin):
    digits = int(spin.props.digits)
    value = spin.props.value
    if value < 0:
        spin.props.text = "Infinity"  # u"\u221E"
    else:
        spin.props.text = '{0:.{1}f}'.format(value, digits)
    return True
self.my_spin.connect('output', spin_output)
```

When the "Infinity"-value is selected and the user presses the "up"-button the value changes to 100 instead of 0.
When i replace "Infinity" with u"\u221E" and the user presses the "up"-button while it is selected, the value changes to 1.

What I want is, that the user can select the values in that order: Infinity, 0, 1, ... 
What is my mistake?

I thought that only the underlying adjustment is changed when the user changes the value and my function is only used to show the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. I wrote the counterpart for the output-signal-handler ... the input-signal-handler :-)

```
def parallel_spin_input(spin, new_value):
    text = spin.get_text()
    if text == u"\u221E":
        value = -1
    else:
        try:
            value = float(text)
        except ValueError:
            return -1
    p = ctypes.c_double.from_address(hash(new_value))
    p.value = value
    return True
self.parallel_spin.connect('input', parallel_spin_input)
```

This seems to work well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the spin button is interpreting the string "infinity" as a string entered by the user, and trying to parse it as a value. The `gtk.Scale` widgets offer a signal called `format-value` which is used to display custom values just like you're trying to do, but I don't see a similar signal for the spin button.

Here is something using a scale that might do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

def scale_output(scale, value):
    if value < 0:
        return "Infinity"  # u"\u221E"
    return "{0}".format(int(value))

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
adjustment = gtk.Adjustment(-1, -1, 100, 1, 1)
scale = gtk.HScale(adjustment)
window.set_default_size(300, 100)
window.add(scale)
scale.connect('format-value', scale_output)
window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```